# Does Barry Allen ever Possess a Blue-ish Lightning Streak?

Tags: dc, the-flash

In the Justice League Comic-Con trailer, Barry's lightning streak is blue-ish in color. Does Flash ever have a blue streak in the comics? Or is it something new in the Justice League movie?

Comment: In all the comics I've read, Barry has a yellow streak (electric effect). Not only him, but all Flashes, Jesse Quick, Impulse, all have yellow streak. HOWEVER, during Flashe's stint as Blue Lantern, he did have a  Blue Streak

Comment: Yeah...! Neither have I read any comic in which his streak is blue. I guess then they realized that lightning is not yellow...

Comment: Zoom is sometimes shown to have blue lightning. In The Flash (CW) this is explained because he took a special drug to try and increase his speed, it caused problems for him, and turns his speed force lightning blue.

Answer (score 3):

**Does Flash ever have a blue streak in the comics?**

### Yes

As noted by [Alexander Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138909/does-barry-allen-ever-possesss-a-blue-ish-lightning-streak/213955#138909) on Amino

> If you don't remember Flash does have blue lightning in the comics Future Flash

[image]

**Is it something new in the JL movie?**

### No

We actually see Flash with two colors in the movies.

Here he is meeting Batman, with predominately blue lightning.

And here he is racing Superman at the end of the movie. Here it seems like he has a combination of blue and white lightning.

And here we have a future Barry Allen vising Bruce Wayne in Batman v Superman. This older and more experienced Barry is now surrounded by white lightning.